# Problema com a formatação de TextInput no React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

Tenho o seguinte componente do React Native que é uma tela para preencher dados de uma atividade:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Switch, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import BarraSuperior from "../../Recursos/BarraSuperior/Index";
import Estilos from './Styles';
import Atividades from '../../Services/sqlite/Atividades';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import normalizador from '../../Recursos/normalizador';
import { useNavigation, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
    
export default function Cadastro() {
    //Define os dados do CRUD
    const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState('')
    const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState('')
    const [descricao, setDescricao] = useState('')
    const [btn, setBtn] = useState(false)
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

    //Métodos do DateTimePicker
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const Navigation = useNavigation()

    // Navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())

    function NavigateToAtividades() {
        Navigation.navigate('Atividades')
    }

    const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
        const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        setDate(currentDate);
    };
    // Muda setShow para true o que faz com que DateTimePicker apareça na tela.
    const showMode = (currentMode) => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
    };
    //Altera o modo de exibição para DatePicker
    const showDatepicker = () => {
        showMode('date');
    };
    //Altera o modo de exibição para TimePicker
    const showTimepicker = () => {
        showMode('time');
    };
    //Formata a data que vai ser mostrada no campo de seleção da data
    const formatData = () => {
        let dia = date.getDate();
        let mes = date.getMonth();
        let ano = date.getFullYear();

        if (dia.toString().length === 1) {
            dia = '0' + dia
        }
        if (mes.toString().length === 1) {
            mes = '0' + (mes + 1)
        }
        return dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano
    }
    //Formata as horas e minutos que vão ser mostrados no campo de seleção de tempo
    const formatTime = () => {
        let hora = date.getHours()
        let minutos = date.getMinutes()

        if (hora.toString().length === 1) {
            hora = '0' + hora
        }
        if (minutos.toString().length === 1) {
            minutos = '0' + minutos
        }
        return hora + ':' + minutos
    }
    //Setter para os campos de texto e botões
    const reset = () => {
        setBtn(false);
        setCategoria(' ');
        setTitulo(' ');
        setDescricao(' ');
        setDate(new Date());
    }
    //Passa os dados para o CRUD
    const save = () => {
        //Verifica se nenhum dos campos obrigatórios estão vazios, se não, é passado os dados para o banco de dados e o usuário é retornardo para a tela de Atividades. Se algum campo estiver vazio, será retornado um Alert
        if (titulo === '' || titulo === ' ') {
            return alert('Digite o Titulo')
        } else if (categoria === '' || categoria === ' ') {
            return alert('Digite a categoria')
        } else {
            Atividades.create({ titulo: titulo, categoria: categoria, descricao: descricao, data: date.toString(), notificar: btn, atrasado: false, concluida: false, dataConcluida: '' })
                .then(alert('Adicionado com sucesso!'))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
            reset()
            NavigateToAtividades()
        }
    }


    return (
        <View style={Estilos.mainView}>
            <BarraSuperior
                conteudo='Nova tarefa'
                onPress={() => Navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
                valor={false} 
                />
            <View style={{flex: 1,justifyContent: 'center', padding: '1%'}}>
            <View style={Estilos.secondaryView}>
                <Text style={Estilos.titulos}>Título da tarefa</Text>
                <TextInput 
                    style={Estilos.campos} 
                    value={titulo} 
                    onChangeText={text => setTitulo(text)}
                    />
                <Text style={Estilos.titulos}>Categoria</Text>
                <TextInput 
                    style={Estilos.campos} 
                    value={categoria} 
                    onChangeText={categoria => setCategoria(categoria)} 
                    />
                <Text style={Estilos.titulos}>Descrição<Text style={Estilos.descricao}> (Opcional)</Text></Text>
                <TextInput 
                    style={Estilos.textoInput} 
                    value={descricao} 
                    multiline
                    scrollEnabled={true}
                    onChangeText={text => setDescricao(text)} 
                    />
                <Text style={Estilos.titulos}>Data</Text>
                <View style={Estilos.data}>
                    <Feather 
                        name='calendar' 
                        color='gold' 
                        size={normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('4%')} 
                        />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatepicker}>
                        <Text style={Estilos.textoData}>{formatData()}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Feather 
                        name='clock' 
                        color='gold' 
                        size={normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('4%')} 
                        />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={showTimepicker}>
                        <Text style={Estilos.textoData}>{formatTime()}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={Estilos.viewSwitch}>
                    <Text style={Estilos.notificar}>Noticar</Text>
                    <Switch 
                        trackColor={{ false: '#dedede', true: '#3e7fff' }} 
                        thumbColor={btn ? '#7eaaff' : '#dedede'} 
                        value={btn} 
                        onValueChange={() => { setBtn(!btn) }} 
                        />
                </View>
            </View>
            
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={Estilos.Btn} onPress={save}>
                <Text style={Estilos.textBtn}>Adicionar</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
            {show && (
                <DateTimePicker
                    minimumDate={new Date}
                    testID="dateTimePicker"
                    value={date}
                    mode={mode}
                    is24Hour={true}
                    display="default"
                    onChange={onChange}
                />
            )}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Com a seguinte formatação:

```js
import {StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import normalizador from "../../Recursos/normalizador";
    
    
export default StyleSheet.create({
    textoData: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('3%'),
        color: 'white'
    },
    descricao : {
        fontFamily: 'Poppins_400Regular',
        fontSize : normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('2%')
    },
    data: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        padding: '3%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        position: 'relative',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        width: '60%',
        height: '8%',
        borderRadius: 20
    },
    textBtn: {
        color: '#FFF',
        fontFamily: 'Poppins_600SemiBold',
        fontSize: normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('4%')
    },
    Btn: {
        minHeight: '7%',
        minWidth: '35%',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderRadius: 20,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    textoInput : {
        padding: '3%',
        width: '95%',
        height: '30%',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#d9d9d9',
        borderRadius: 20
    },
    secondaryView: {
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        elevation: 20,
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: '4%'
    },
    mainView : {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'stretch'
    },
    titulos: {
        fontFamily: 'Poppins_700Bold',
        fontSize: normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('4%'),
        color: 'black',
    },
    campos: {
        width: '95%',
        height: '8%',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#d9d9d9',
        borderRadius: 20
    },
    viewSwitch: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    notificar: {
        fontSize: normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('3%')
    }
})
```

Meu problema é que cada vez que abro o teclado para digitar o texto os componentes da tela são redimensionados ao invés deles simplesmente se moverem para cima, exemplo:

Tela sem abrir o TextInput:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela após abrir o TextInput:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso fazer para corrigir esse erro de formatação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acho que está causando essa distorção dos componentes pela aparição do teclado, é o uso de valores de porcentagem como medida. Acontece coisa semelhante na *web*:

```css
.window {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #eee;
}

.distorced-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="distorced-container">
    Hello, World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Ao redimensionar o *container* externo (o retângulo de cor cinza mais clara), você verá que, por o *container* interno (o retângulo de cor cinza mais escura) ter suas medidas baseadas em porcentagem, a mudança das dimensões do *container* externo faz com que ele fique distorcido.

Isso porque o *container* interno está dimensionado dessa forma:

- A largura deve ser **50% da largura total do elemento pai**;
- A altura deve ser **10% da altura total do elemento pai**;

Se as dimensões totais do elemento pai são `500px` x `100px`, as dimensões totais desse elemento será `250px` x `10px`. No caso, como é `200px` x `20px`, então será `100px` x `2px`. Ou seja, as dimensões desse elemento interno depende das dimensões do seu elemento pai.

Do mesmo modo é no React Native. Esse *container* externo (`<div class="window">`) é semelhante à janela visível do aplicativo. E esse *container* interno (`<div class="distorced-container">`) é semelhante ao campo de texto.

Quando a janela visível é modificada pelo teclado, as dimensões do campo de texto são atualizadas com base na porcentagem que você definiu em relação à largura da janela e do seu componente pai.

---

Assim, uma sugestão é que você também use a função `widthPercentageToDP`, juntamente com a `heightPercentageToDP`, para definir as medidas dos componentes – conforme eu, pessoalmente, uso – pois assim, apesar de você passar uma porcentagem para ela, será retornado um valor "fixo".

```js
export default StyleSheet.create({
    ...
    textoInput : {
        padding: '3%',
        width: normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('95%'),
        height: normalizador.heightPercentageToDP('30%'),
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#d9d9d9',
        borderRadius: 20
    },
    ...
    campos: {
        width: normalizador.widthPercentageToDP('95%'),
        height: normalizador.heightPercentageToDP('8%'),
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#d9d9d9',
        borderRadius: 20
    },
    ...
})
```

Isso porque a função será executada somente na criação do objeto e, portanto, retornará o valor somente uma vez. Por exemplo:

```js
function computeWidth(value) {
  const properValue = typeof value === 'number' ? value : parseFloat(value);
  
  return window.innerWidth * properValue / 100;
}

console.log({
  valorConstanteAdaptativo: '50%',
  valorConstanteComputado: computeWidth('50%'),
});
```

Enquanto o valor `'50%'` vai fazer com que o elemento mude suas dimensões (se adapte) de acordo com as dimensões do seu elemento pai, o valor retornado por `computeWidth('50%')` vai calcular a dimensão de `50%` da tela uma única vez e lá permanecerá até que a função seja chamada novamente, que será quando o objeto possa ter sido criado novamente.

Eu criei [esse *snippet* no Snack](https://snack.expo.io/VkdL0ww!K) para demonstrar como de fato isso funciona no React Native. No iOS, parece que não há alteração nas dimensões por parte do teclado, conforme ocorre no Android e na *web*.

[image]

Veja que, com a ativação do teclado, o `<TextInput />` baseado em porcentagem (o de cima) ficou achatado, enquanto que o `<TextInput />` baseado no valor computado pela função (o de baixo) ficou "intacto".

Comment: Muito obrigado! Realmente, depois de várias tentativas percebi que os componentes estavam sendo redimensionados com base no tamanho da tela disponível depois da abertura do teclado. Só não sabia como deixar fixo o tamanho dos componentes usando porcentagem (a sua sujestão). Então, usei a sua ideia para resolver o problema e a da sujestão de resposta abaixo para melhorar a experiência de uso do app.